# Different answers for the same questions, exam 70-515

Tags: .net

I have two different answers for same questions (taken from a study guide). The Questions are:

*1. You are implementing an ASP.NET Web application. Users will authenticate to the 
application with an ID. The application will allow new users to register for an account. The 
application will generate an ID for the user based on the users full name. You need to 
implement this registration functionality. Which two actions should you perform? (Each 
correct answer presents part of the solution. Choose two.)*

A. Configure the SqlMembershipProvider in the web.config file.
B. Configure the SqlProfileProvider in the web.config file.
C. Create an ASP.NET page that contains a default CreateUserWizard control to create a new 
user account.
D. Create an ASP.NET page that contains a custom form that collects the user information and 
then uses the Membership.CreateUser method to create a new user account.

Responses are A-D and A-B (I think that is A-D)

*2. You are implementing an ASP.NET application that uses data-bound GridView controls in 
multiple pages. You add JavaScript code to periodically update specific types of data items 
in these GridView controls. You need to ensure that the JavaScript code can locate the 
HTML elements created for each row in these GridView controls, without needing to be 
changed if the controls are moved from one page to another. What should you do?*

A. Replace the GridView control with a ListView control.
B. Set the ClientIDMode attribute to Predictable in the web.config file.
C. Set the ClientIDRowSuffix attribute of each unique GridView control to a different value.
D. Set the @ OutputCache directives VaryByControl attribute to the ID of the GridView control.

Responses are B and C (I think that is C)

*3. You are developing an ASP.NET Web application. You create a master page. The master 
page requires a region where you can add page-specific content by using the ASP.NET 
page designer. You need to add a control to the master page to define the region. Which 
control should you add?*

A. Content
B. ContentPlaceHolder
C. PlaceHolder
D. Substitution

Responses are B and C (I think that is B)

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

For question 1, "A and D" is correct. There's no mention of profile information, so there's no reason to setup the profile provider.

For question 2, C is correct, since you will be updating individual rows, not the control itself.

For question 3, B is correct, since you need a place-holder for *content* that will be provided by the pages that use this master page.